# How to skip preview-window within context menu [(...)-Menu] with JavaScript (Script Editor Web Part)

Tags: javascript, web-part, script

I would like to skip the preview-window (red marked in my screenshot) within the context menu [(...)-Menu] of a document in a library and go straight into the menu (which is opened when clicking in the preview-window again on the (...). Therefore I would like to know a **solution with JavaScript** (which I can post into a **Script Editor Web Part**), cuz I don't have any access to SharePoint Designer 2013 and also not to Top-Level-Site.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting following script in Script Editor webpart on the page. Hope this might help you out.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ms-list-itemLink > a").each(function(){
        this.setAttribute("onclick","ShowECBMenuForTr(this.parentNode, event); return false;");
    });
});
</script>
```

**Note** : I have used jQuery instead of pure javascript.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked and you saved me much time :)